# Only with ROS - avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having an issue with my Arduino using ros.  I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with Jade.

When I upload the blink tutorial to my Arduino it works okay.  But if as soon as I try adding #include <ros.h> or try to upload any of the ros_lib examples it errors out while trying to upload the sketch.  Below are two screenshots showing the sucessful and unsucessful attempts.  I searched for a few hours trying to find a solution but could not come to a solution.

[image description http://expanse.us/bloguploads/ArduinoBlink.png](http://expanse.us/bloguploads/ArduinoBlink.png)
[image description http://expanse.us/bloguploads/ArduinoROSincluded.png](http://expanse.us/bloguploads/ArduinoROSincluded.png)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238048/only-with-ros---avrdude:-stk500_recv():-programmer-is-not-responding/) by [Uncle_Jew](https://answers.ros.org/users/27280/uncle_jew/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-06-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-06-25**:
It looks like it starts uploading fine, and then gets interrupted partway through the upload process. Setting up rosserial doesn't doesn't change the upload process, so this doesn't seem like an issue that could be caused by ROS.

**Comment by [Uncle_Jew](https://answers.ros.org/users/27280/uncle_jew/) on 2016-06-25**:
Actually I take it back.  After more testing it turns out not to be an issue only related to ROS.  After your comment I did some more testing and other non ros examples are running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While it is not ideal I did come up with a temporary solution :/

I isolated the error to only happening in Ubuntu.  Since it seems to be something there I decided to add the ros_lib folder on Windows and upload all my code there.  Then run ROS in Virtualbox with Ubuntu.  Would be nice to do it all through Ubuntu but as long as it is working I'm happy.

---

Originally posted by [Uncle_Jew](https://answers.ros.org/users/27280/uncle_jew/) with karma: 16 on 2016-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0